# How can I use the data in private area when I click the button

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to get bytes from a private class and using it in btn.click.What should I do for doing this?

Here is the sample code:

```
private void CameraConnnection_DataReceived(object sender, BReceivedData x)
        {
            byte[] data = e.ReceivedData;
        }

        private void BtnGetImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            unsafe
            {
               byte a[]= e.ReceivedData;// This is not working how can I get received data from there.There is a event and it's triggering from there.
            }
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the `e.ReceivedData` value of `CameraConnnection_DataReceived()` in `BtnGetImage_Click()`?  One method cannot access another's local variables because, well, they're local.  You'll need to promote `data` to a field to access it from both methods.

Comment: Yes that is what I tried.Can you explain it how can I do?@ Lance U. Matthews

Comment: I am trying to access e.ReceivedData in CameraConnnection_DataReceived() for btnGetImage.Click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `EventArgs` class doesn't have `ReceivedData` field or property, the code below *doesn't compile*:

```
private void BtnGetImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  // Compile time error: ReceivedData doesn't exist
  byte a[] = e.ReceivedData;
```

You can obtain and *save* `ReceivedData` on `DataReceived` event but use it on `Click`:

```
private byte[] receivedData = new byte[0];

private void CameraConnnection_DataReceived(object sender, BReceivedData x)
{
    // ?? new byte[0] - to be on the safe side and never have null
    receivedData = e.ReceivedData ?? new byte[0];
}

private void BtnGetImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  byte[] a = receivedData;

  ...
}
```

Comment: It worked.Thank you.@Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: I have just a little question.It did not come as filled(It ıs coming as 0.) when I compiled the code.What should I do different@Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: n_stckwff: it's time to debug: please, put a break point on `recievedData = ...` and inspect what's sent via `e.RecievedData`

Comment: I just debugged know.The part that you wrote is working.Thank you again.@ Dmitry Bychenko